# Get DOM element from template in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone.js to display a list of people and their data.

Every person has it's own `<div>`. The div is generated by `_.template` and contains `<input>` fields to display the person's data so it can be adjusted.

There is also a button with `class=".save"`. In my view I have a function bound to the click of this button. I am looking for the best approach to get the values of the `<input>`-tags in the `div` belonging to the model.

Here is my approach but I'm wondering if there's a **better** one. In my template I have dyanmically assigned ID's for the DOM elements based on the ID of the model. I use the same logic to find back the element in the view.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<input value="<%=name%>" id="name_<%=id%>"/>
<input value="<%=age%>" id="age_<%=id%>"/>
<input value="<%=address%>" id="address_<%=id%>"/>
<button class=".save">Save</button>
```

**VIEW**

```
events:{
    "click .save":"savePerson"
},

savePerson: function(){
    this.model.set({
        name: $("#name" + this.model.id).val(),
        address: $("#address_" + this.model.id).val(),
        age: $("#age_" + this.model.id).val()
    });
    this.model.save();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If every person is a different view instance with its own template, you can just **define the scope of the selector for the view's template**:

TEMPLATE

```
<form id="<%-id%>">
  <input value="<%-name%>" name="name"/>
  <input value="<%-age%>" name="age"/>
  <input value="<%-address%>" name="address"/>
  <button class=".save">Save</button>
</form>
```

VIEW

```
events:{
    "click .save":"savePerson"
},

savePerson: function(){
    this.model.set({
        name: this.$("input[name='name']").val(),
        age: this.$("input[name='age']").val(),
        address: this.$("input[name='address']").val()
    });
    this.model.save();
}
```

Otherwise, if you have many persons in the same template/view instance (not nice), just catch the current person's id `var personId = this.$("#"+this.model.id)`, to use this `personId` inside selectors above.

PS: I use `<%-value%>` instead of `<%=value%>` to interpolate this value, and have it be HTML-escaped.

Comment: That's awesome! I have one view per person so that works great. So `$el` contains the HTML of the rendered view? I never really understood the documentation on this one.

Comment: Your view's el is the container you place your templated content, and where all the event binding happens. So yes, it is what contains your DOM element, and the use of $el is a handy reference instead of re-wrapping $() the DOM element all the time.

Comment: Using `this.$()` would be more idiomatic than `$(..., this.$el)` or `this.$el.find(...)`: ["If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a **$** function that runs queries scoped within the view's element."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)